# MySQL - Insert rows date and time between all intervals

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a mysql database like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   startdate   |   starttime  |    enddate    |    endtime   |   status  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2020-03-04   |   04:30:00   |  2020-03-04   |   09:00:00   |  running  |
|  2020-03-04   |   11:30:00   |  2020-03-04   |   19:30:00   |  running  |
|  2020-03-05   |   05:00:00   |  2020-03-05   |   11:15:00   |  running  |
|  2020-03-05   |   12:30:00   |  2020-03-05   |   22:08:00   |  running  |

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want know if is possible, create a php(or something like that) script to insert all intervals between date/time and create a row with status "stopped".

Example:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   startdate   |   starttime  |    enddate    |    endtime   |   status  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2020-03-04   |   00:00:00   |  2020-03-04   |   04:30:00   |  stopped  | *created by this script
|  2020-03-04   |   04:30:00   |  2020-03-04   |   09:00:00   |  running  |
|  2020-03-04   |   09:00:00   |  2020-03-04   |   11:30:00   |  stopped  | *
|  2020-03-04   |   11:30:00   |  2020-03-04   |   19:30:00   |  running  |

etc.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible?

Sorry my english

Comment: How do you know when its stopped?

Comment: Every space of time which is not running, would be stopped. The script could be started after first cronologic date and stops at current date

Comment: I think you mean column.

Comment: May I ask what's purpose of adding these rows? Is this for a report or another query? Because there might be other options....

Comment: @SOS, I have a programmable logic controller that can give me the information of the periods that the machine was running. I put this information in the database and I can calculate the availability (OEE). The entire period that the machine is not running, it is supposedly stopped. I need this data entered into the database for reporting purposes and to be able to justify these stops. I still haven't found a way to have the periods in which the machine is stopped in the database. I welcome suggestions for other ways to work this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using MySQL 8+, you could use the [LAG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) function to compare the current record's start date/time with the previous record's end date/time. When there's a difference, use those values to create the missing time span:

- Previous End Date/Time ==> New Start Date/Time
- Current Start Date/Time ==> New End Date/Time

**Query:**

This query will return the missing records, which you can insert into your table if desired.

```
WITH cte AS (
   -- using single datetime value for simpler logic
   SELECT * 
      , LAG (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EndDate, ' ', EndTime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 1, NULL) 
            OVER (ORDER BY EndDate, EndTime) AS PrevEndDateTime
      , STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(StartDate, ' ', StartTime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS StartDateTime            
   FROM   YourTable
)
SELECT CAST( DATE_FORMAT(COALESCE(PrevEndDateTime, StartDate),'%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE ) AS StartDate
       , CAST( DATE_FORMAT(COALESCE(PrevEndDateTime, StartDate),'%H:%i:%s') AS TIME ) AS StartTime
       , StartDate AS EndDate
       , StartTime AS EndTime
       , 'stopped' AS Status
FROM   cte
WHERE  StartDateTime <> PrevEndDateTime
OR     PrevEndDateTime IS NULL
```

**Test Data:**

> ```
> StartDate  | StartTime | EndDate    | EndTime  | status 
> :--------- | :-------- | :--------- | :------- | :------
> 2020-03-02 | 01:30:00  | 2020-03-02 | 09:00:00 | running
> 2020-03-04 | 04:30:00  | 2020-03-04 | 09:00:00 | running
> 2020-03-04 | 11:30:00  | 2020-03-04 | 19:30:00 | running
> 2020-03-05 | 05:00:00  | 2020-03-05 | 11:15:00 | running
> 2020-03-05 | 12:30:00  | 2020-03-05 | 22:08:00 | running
> ```

**Missing Records:**

> ```
> StartDate  | StartTime | EndDate    | EndTime  | Status 
> :--------- | :-------- | :--------- | :------- | :------
> 2020-03-02 | 00:00:00  | 2020-03-02 | 01:30:00 | stopped
> 2020-03-02 | 09:00:00  | 2020-03-04 | 04:30:00 | stopped
> 2020-03-04 | 09:00:00  | 2020-03-04 | 11:30:00 | stopped
> 2020-03-04 | 19:30:00  | 2020-03-05 | 05:00:00 | stopped
> 2020-03-05 | 11:15:00  | 2020-03-05 | 12:30:00 | stopped
> ```

demo *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71f98d2ffd71905ab8c46bf006abf9df)*

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped!